# Is it save to send hashed password in req.user using passportJS?

Tags: javascript, express, cookies, passwords, passport.js

I am using an express backend restricted by passportJS, I noticed that the default setting seems to be sending the user information in req.user (including the password) for every request done after a log in. Are these additional properties sent with a request called cookies? And is including the hashed password safe?

Answer (score 0):

The `user` object does not contain data from the request.

It is stored *internally* and associated with the token (be that a JWT, session ID or whatever) that is sent with the request.

Comment: Okay, so to understand the flow: Is (in my case) express-session identifying the unique token it has given to a client before, storing it in req.session and then passport middleware takes that information and adds the req.user object?